# Get part of a string with dynamic length in C

Tags: c, string, char

I got the following string from the user:
char *abc = "a234bc567d";
but all the numbers can have different lengths than in this example (letters are constants).
How can I get each part of numbers? (again, it can be 234 or 23743 or something else..)

I tried to use strchr and strncpy but I need to allocate memory for this (for strncpy), and I hope there is a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show some code!

Comment: explain the `23743` or `something else`.

Comment: Do you need to extract the numbers as strings or do you want to convert them to ints? Do the numbers need to be stored somewhere or do you just need to use them as you find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
char *abc = "a234bc567d";
char *ptr = abc; // point to start of abc

// While not at the end of the string
while (*ptr != '\0') 
{
  //  If position is the start of a number
  if (isdigit(*ptr))
  {
    // Get value (assuming base 10), store end position of number in ptr
    int value = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10); 

    printf("Found value %d\n", value);
  }
  else
  {
    ptr++; // Increase pointer
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to extract the parts of the user input that contain numbers ... and the sequence of numbers can be variable ... but the letters are fixed i.e. a or b or c or d. Correct ... ? The following program may help you. I tried it for strings "a234bc567d", "a23743bc567d" and "a23743bc5672344d". Works ...

```
int main()
{
        char *sUser = "a234bc567d";
        //char *sUser = "a23743bc567d";
        //char *sUser = "a23743bc5672344d";

        int iLen = strlen(sUser);
        char *sInput = (char *)malloc((iLen+1) * sizeof(char));

        strcpy(sInput, sUser);
        char *sSeparator = "abcd";
        char *pToken = strtok(sInput, sSeparator);

        while(1)
        {
                if(pToken == NULL)
                        break;

                printf("Token = %s\n", pToken);

                pToken = strtok(NULL, sSeparator);
        }  
        return 0;
}
```